# javascript client (Flutter) with secure server (SSL) certificates

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

my backend is an asp.net web api server hosted as a secure server with a certificate. when I navigate to the url is secure. so this part looks good. then I FTP my browser app (Flutter but could be Angular, React etc ) to the same server. I navigate to myflutterapp.xxx and flutter app looks great and works as designed  except it is marked as insecure by chrome. so how many certificates to I need? possible answers:
1 i do not need the certificate on the server app only flutter app
2 I need both

Answer (score 0):

I was having a brain fart as I put the corticate on the asp.net server component . it needs to be on the web app (Flutter javascript) that will be run in the users browser and where the HTTPS handshaking takes place.